# Is it possible to have "local" keyspace in a cassandra cluster with multiple datacenters

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes

Can I prevent a keyspace from syncing over to another datacenter by NOT including the other datacenter in my keyspace replication definition?
Apparently, this is not the case.

In my own test, I have set up two Kubernetes clusters in GCP, each serves as a Cassandra datacenter.  Each k8s clusters have 3 nodes.

I set up datacenter DC-WEST first, and create a keyspace demo using this:
`CREATE KEYSPACE demo WITH replication = {‘class’: ‘NetworkTopologyStrategy’, ‘DC-WEST’ : 3};`

Then I set up datacenter DC-EAST, without adding any use keyspaces.

To join the two data centers, I modify the `CASSANDRA_SEEDS` environment variable in the Cassandra StatefulSet YAML to include seeds nodes from both datacenters (I use host networking).

But after that, I notice the keyspace `demo` is synced over to DC-EAST, even though the keyspace only has DC-WEST in the replication.

```
cqlsh> select data_center from system.local
... ;

data_center
-------------
DC-EAST     <-- Note: this is from the DC-EAST datacenter

(1 rows)
cqlsh> desc keyspace demo

CREATE KEYSPACE demo WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC-WEST': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

So we see in DC-EAST the `demo` keyspace which should be replicated only on DC-WEST!  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cassandra replication strategies control where data is placed, but the actual schema (the existence of the table/datacenters/etc) is global.

If you create a keyspace that only lives in one DC, all other DCs will still see the keyspace in their schema, and will even make the directory structure on disk, though no data will be replicated to those hosts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I think this was my misunderstanding.  I was under the wrong impression that if a keyspace is only replicated within certain DC, other DC will not be see it.  Now I have the correct understanding and I can close the question now.  Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I have a followup question.  Suppose I have application data that I want to replicate acroess the DCs for high availability, but I also have local user data that I want to keep private to the local DC and not accessible from other DCs, how can I do that?  Can I do it with one multi-DC cassandra cluster, or do I need to have additional cassandra clusters running locally in each DC?

Comment: Replication factor is set per keyspace, and privileges can be set per keyspace, so create a user for the multi-dc keyspace, and create a different user for the single-dc use case.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify how you deployed you Cassandra cluster in Kubernetes, but it looks like your nodes in `DC-WEST` may be configured to say that they are `DC-EAST`.

I would check the [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) for the stateful set in `DC-WEST`. Maybe it has the `DC-EAST` value for `cassandra-rackdc.properties`(?). More info on the `cassandra-rackdc.properties` file [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/initialize/initSingleDS.html).

Comment: I set the data center name through the CASSANDRA_DC environment variable in the statefulset yaml, and I confirm that the DC name is set correctly for each DC.  The real issue is my misunderstanding on how Cassandra works, as explained by the answer by Jeff.  Thanks.